# Serialization of array of xml elements already within a xmlAny Element

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization

```
<Fruits>

            <FruitName>Amla</FruitName> 
            <FruitPrice>10 US DOLLARS</FruitPrice> 

            <Origin>
                <Country>INDIA</Country> 
                <NativeName>GOOSEBERRY</NativeName> 
                <Availability>PLENTY</Availability> 
            </Origin>

            <OtherInfo>
                <FiberPercentage>1.11</FiberPercentage> 
                <MagnesiumPercentage>0.02</MagnesiumPercentage> 
            </OtherInfo>
```

While De serializing the above XML structure, I use something like,

Xml

```
XmlElement("FruitsList")]
public List<Fruits> FruitsImport { get; set; }
```

In Fruits Class, I have something like:

```
    [XmlAnyElement]
    public List<XmlElement> FruitElements { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Origin")]
    public List<XmlElement> FruitOrigin { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("OtherInfo")]
    public List<XmlElement> OtherInfo { get; set; }
```

`FruitElement` retrieves the `FruitName` and `FruitPrice`.
`FruitOrigin` retrives Country `Info` alone.
`OtherInfo` retrives `FiberPercentage` alone.

Any ideas on how to get all the info under `<Origin>` and `<OtherInfo>` tags ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you have elements nested in both `<origin>` and `<otherinfo>` tags, you need to define a class for them as well when performing deserialization.

```
[XmlElement("Origin")]
public List<Origins> FruitOrigin { get; set; }
```

You would define the origin class the same way as you did for fruit class.

(The skeleton of Origin class would be something as below:

```
[Serializable]
public class Origin
{
    [XmlAnyElement]
    public List<XmlElement> OriginElements { get; set; }
}
```

)

Comment: @now he who must not be named My pleasure, glad I could help you

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to write XSD schema for the XML and generate class from XSD schema using [XSD.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/x6c1kb0s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), this way you can validate that always XML and class matches to XSD and never have issue with Serialization/ Deserialization.

You can create batch file like below to generate class from xsd schema:

```
del Configuration.AutoGenerated.cs
"%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin\xsd" Test.Configuration.xsd /c /n:Test.Configuration 

rename Test_Configuration.cs Configuration.AutoGenerated.cs
pause
```

You can see more usage examples at above link for XSD.exe.
It will generate partial classes so you can easily extend it further if required.